# Problem : Solve $|x^2+x-4| =|x^2-4| +|x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Problem : Solve $|x^2+x-4| =|x^2-4| +|x|$

We can find the critical point of each modulus function individually then we  get : $x =\pm 2;$ and $x = 0$ $x = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2}$

So there are six intervals on the number line ( as per definition of modulus function) for which we can check the behaviour of mod. function which are :

$(-\infty , -2.55) , (-2.5 , -2), (-2,0) , (0,1.45),(1.45, 2), (2, \infty)$

Please suggest whether this is the correct method of approaching this problem. Thanks .

Comment: Your method is fine.  Just test a point in each interval.

Comment: It will work, quite tedious. Our functions are **very** special, so there is a shortcut.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas what is the short cut on this . thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From triangle inequality, we have
$$\vert x^2-4 + x \vert \leq \vert x^2-4 \vert + \vert x \vert$$
where equality holds iff $x$ and $x^2-4$ have the same sign. Hence, this gives us two cases:

$1$. $x \geq 0$ and $x^2-4 \geq 0$. This implies $x \geq 2$.

$2$. $x \leq 0$ and $x^2-4 \leq 0$. This implies $-2 \leq x \leq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$|x| + |y| = |x + y|$ when $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, or $xy\ge 0$. (Why?)

So, here $(x^2 - 4)x \ge 0 \Rightarrow x(x+2)(x - 2) \ge 0 \Rightarrow x \in [-2,0]\cup [2,\infty)$